# How to make an object property unique?

Tags: oop

I'm learning about the principles of OOP and was doing this exercise question.

> We are given a school. The school has classes of students. Each class has
>   a set of teachers. Each teacher teaches a set of courses. The students
>   have a name and **unique** number in the class. Classes have a **unique** text
>   identifier. Teachers have names. Courses have a name, count of classes
>   and count of exercises. The teachers as well as the students are people.
>   Your task is to model the classes (in terms of OOP) along with their
>   attributes and operations define the class hierarchy and create a class
>   diagram with Visual Studio.

I am not sure how to ensure the parts in bold. What I was doing was just normally making the adjectives properties. I am not sure how to ensure that other objects are not able to have the same unique number. I was thinking of using the Dictionary data structure which doesn't allow duplicates. I would use this unique number as the key and the object to be its value. Is my line of thought correct here?

Comment: to make a classNo unique:: `private static int classNo = 0` now make a `public static` getter for this class, in the getter class also increment `classNo` by `1`. So each time student request for his/her `classNo` he/she will get a unique  `classNo`. same for other fields..

Comment: Wow this is an elegant solution. Is this normal practice or considered a design Pattern? I have yet to touch on that.

Comment: I learnt this in a design pattern class, i guess it's considering a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

you can have for example static private array property (same for every instance of a class) in class, and on the constructor You can check if this value had been used